# How do I report a connection problem in Azure network?

Tags: azure, networking

I have a VM located in US East 2 which I haven't been able to access for over an hour.  The portal shows it's still running, and there are no network issues according to status.azure.com.  However, when I run traceroute it reveals a problem:

```
  6    38 ms    14 ms    13 ms  microsoft-10.gw.opentransit.net [193.251.249.230]
  7    17 ms    15 ms    17 ms  ae22-0.ear01.mrs21.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.230.76]
  8   108 ms   103 ms   104 ms  be-21-0.ibr02.mrs21.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.33.147]
  9   105 ms   103 ms   104 ms  be-8-0.ibr02.par30.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.29.168]
 10   104 ms   103 ms   104 ms  be-3-0.ibr02.bio70.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.29.155]
 11   104 ms   104 ms   104 ms  be-4-0.ibr04.orf70.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.29.234]
 12   105 ms   104 ms   103 ms  be-6-0.ibr04.bn6.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.29.143]
 13   105 ms   103 ms   103 ms  ae162-0.icr04.bn6.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.20.138]
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

How can I notify Microsoft of this issue?

Comment: Open a ticket using the support option in the azure portal?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: The privilege to open a ticket costs $29/month.  Seems unreasonable for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Azure Monitor Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/network-insights-overview)  or [Azure Network Watcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitoring-overview)

Both are used to monitor your explicit network - vpns, ngs, etc.

You can also see the complete graph of your network and see what can connect to whom.

It has explicit health checks as well and alerts for when your VMs shutdown.

Beyond this in a production environment setup a load balancer with 2 vms where if one falls another one comes up instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There's an awful lot to read through to get to grips with that, and I'm not sure it will help with why the outside world can't access my server.  It's live and my business depends on it, so I bit the bullet and tried to sign up for a developer support plan at $29/month, but each time I try it reports "An error occurred.
Please try again later".  Help!